# How to manage session tokens among various client apps (android/iphone) from server side php and mysql?

Tags: php, android, mysql, rest, session

I have a rest API developed using php and mysql.

I need manage different client apps including  Android and iPhone. I just want to allow only one user from one type of device.

For instance: if a user is using the app on Android and iPhone at the same time, this can be allowed. However, if a user tries to use the app more than one time on the same device, either Android or iPhone, it would not be allowed.

How I can achieve this? I am issuing 3 types of tokens at a time, such as `token_iphone`, `token_android`, etc. Currently my problem is, if any user logged in from the same type of device, the first instance the user started get its token expired or replaced with the new one.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried storing the connection data into a DB and check there, if a user is already signed it or not?

Comment: Yes, but with token only, i just wanted to prevent the  user to login from the same type device again if he already logged in with the same type device. thanks

Comment: Can I ask why this cannot be allowed? Is it a coding issue or is it a business decision?

Comment: Well, store the session **and** the device type. In that way you can check from what device the session already exists and allow/deny the procedure.

Comment: Yes, it is a business decision from the client.thanks

Comment: As Dainis says, associate the session with the device. If the user attempts to log in from another Android device either return the previous session, so there is only one session per Android device, or return an error saying are you already logged in on Device X and you cannot log in again. Frankly that is a terrible idea from a user experience perspective, but if the client wants it what can you do :-)

Comment: Thanks, Dainis and Cormac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i were you I'd manage this with memcached, you create an array identified by the username key and for each token you add to this array a couple device => token, when you have a conflict you either pull the correct token from the array or block the new device. if you have several servers you could also mange php sessions via memcached

```
User_a {
    iphone: 12345,
    android:67890,
    pc: abcdef
}
```